# How to mount an APFS formatted volume created on macOS 10.12.1 on macOS 10.12.2?

Tags: macos, mount, downgrade, apfs

According to [this thread from Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/67007), an APFS volume created on macOS 10.12.1 is not mountable on macOS 10.12.2, because of the incompatible changes.

I put some important files in my external drive formatted as APFS, and now I would like to access the data. I tried this:

```
diskutil apfs list
```

This:

```
sudo fsck_apfs disk1s2
```

And this:

```
diskutil apfs addVolume disk1s2 APFS MyVolume
```

The error message is similar to what mentioned in the above thread:

```
$ diskutil apfs -IHaveBeenWarnedThatAPFSIsPreReleaseAndThatIMayLoseData list

======================================================================================================
ENUMERATION OF ALL CURRENT APFS OBJECTS
   apfs call: sizeForContainer: err=-69808="Some information was unavailable during an internal lookup"
   apfs call: freeSpaceForContainer: err=-69808="Some information was unavailable during an internal lookup"
|
|-- APFS CONTAINER REFERENCE = disk1s2
---------------------------------------------------------------------

$ sudo fsck_apfs disk1s2

** Checking volume.
** Checking the container superblock.
error: nx_incompatible_features has unsupported flags: (0x1)
   Container superblock is invalid.
** The volume disk1s2 could not be verified completely.
```

My questions are:

- Is there an official utility that help me to mount the volume?

  - Or to upgrade the old APFS to the new APFS?
- Is there any way to downgrade my macOS 10.12.2 to 10.12.1?

  - I don't have "Install macOS Sierra.app" in hand, is there any "secret" way to download a previous version of macOS? (I mean previous versions of Sierra, not El Capitan or earlier releases)
  - I don't have Time Machine backups or similar. I would like to fresh install macOS 10.12.1 on my old MacBook, mount the volume, and copy it elsewhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you'll have to try find someone still on 10.12.1, or who has the installer.

Lessons learned:

1. Don't use betas for mission-critical tasks.
2. Keep installers.
3. Keep backups.

Comment: Thanks for your warm suggestions! I do keep installers and that's why I need to mount the external drive! The installers are too huge so that I put all of them in the external drive!

Comment: @SiuChingPong-AsukaKenji- But if you needed to use any of the installers on a computer running a version of OS X older than Sierra…??

Comment: @timothymh : All my macOS devices use Sierra. When I need to use the images, I just burn them on USB thumb drive, or mount them directly as a drive in a VM. And yes, I know there's a warning saying that APFS is pre-release software, but according to my previous experience in using `btrfs` or `ext4`, there was no incompatibility problems. I trust Apple and I thought the warning was no more than a warm reminder. I was wrong.